# Smooth scrolling to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use buttons to scroll to the right or left in my container. It works but I want it to work smooth..

How van I achieve this? Do I need another plugin or is there a simple fix?

```
$(button).on('click', function(){
  flavoursContainer.scrollLeft += 220; 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to achieve that:

```
$(button).on('click', function(){
  $(flavoursContainer).animate({scrollLeft: $(flavoursContainer).scrollLeft() + 220}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#addclickable element').bind('click', function(event) {
    $('#addtargetelement or div').stop().animate({
      scrollLeft: $('.a').offset().left
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```